# What is the difference between machine learning approaches and Fourier series to fit a curve to data graph?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, curve-fitting, fourier-transform

As I know machine learning(at least in some problems) tries to fit a curve to data graph. And I think Fourier transform tried to do it. But machine learning use a hypothesis curve with the formula like `h = w1x1 + w2x2 + ... + wnxn` but Fourier uses a combination of `Sin()/Cos()` functions.

What is the difference? Why machine learning doesn't use a `Sin()/Cos()` combination like Fourier series/transforms?

Answer (score 0):

Using Fourier series is machine learning.
Machine/Statistical learning is just a general term for all kinds of tasks where learning from data is required.